# SQL select from 2 tables with 2 conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi i have two tables in mysql and i want to select from both of them and list things with both condicions true.

```
Friends :
id         iduser     idfriend
0             44            56
1             44            102
2             10             66
3              10            85
4              44            10

Users:
id         name                email                   isonline
44         john          john@gmail.com                   1
10         joe           joe@yahoo.com                    1
185        mark          mark@so.com                      0
```

Example :  im user 44 and i want to get all my friends which are online

So i would exec some sql like :

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE iduser=44 AND SELECT FROM * FROM users WHERE isonline=1
```

I know i cant do it this way and i also search stackowerflow and i found some which didnt work for me 
I just want to get something like : (if im user 44)

10     Joe      joe@yahoo.com

And i dont want to get myself
Thank you for all answers

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
select u.* from friends f
join users u on f.idfriend = u.id
where f.iduser = 44 and u.isonline = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM friends f
INNER JOIN users u
ON f.idfriend = u.id
WHERE f.iduser = 44 AND u.isonline = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) . Joins are used to make a link between two tables generally using a relation. In your case, the relation is user(id) and friends(iduser). Once the join is done, you can select fields from both tables.

```
SELECT u.* FROM friends f
INNER JOIN users u 
ON f.idfriend = u.id
WHERE f.iduser = 44 AND u.isonline = 1
```